# AngularJS to Java Server to Payment gateway back to AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, payment-gateway

We are trying to redirect to a third party payment provider.

This is what we want to accomplish:

```
AngularJS has the payment amount and items which are posted to Java server > 

Java server, verifies items and price, forwards and post details to to payment gateway >

Moneris payment gateway, gets post request, upon payment complete redirects back to client
```

The issue we are running into:
Can Java post and redirect at the same time?
If we do

```
AngularJS > java > AngularJS > Moneris > AngularJS
```

The concerns are preventing the client from editing the values, any step of the way.

Answer (score 3):

**Overview of the solution:**
We solved the problem by having the AngularJS client create 2 separate request.  One to our Java server, one to the payment-gateway.

The Java server will keep checking for the payment-gateway to reply.  When it does, it lets the client know what happened.

**More details:**
The client AngularJS makes an AJAX request to the Java server.

The Java server, holds this request in a loop, constantly checking the payment gateway for success.

When a reply is received, the server replies back to the AngularJS interface with the results.

AngularJS interface then redirects to the correct page.